# How to represents multiple layers in QGIS using time slider?

Tags: qgis, netcdf

Conecting **QGIS** to a **WMS server** I obtain a multiple layers representing windspeed calculated by a meteo model.

The values are into a **netCDS file**. The **WMS** capacity permits me obtain and visualize the values in some diferents barb or arrow representation.

How can I use a time-slider to move the pngs by the time step of the *"time variable"* ? Is there any plugin to do that ?

Comment: have you tried with the plugin TimeManger? https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/timemanager/

Comment: I can not find the timestamp (Time Format in TimeManager) to perform the value.